# in c, what does mean sizeof()..[-1]

Tags: c, pointers, int, size

I am trying to understand the code piece below
But I could not solve it,(especially )

```
void fun(char **p)
{
  char *t;
  t = (p+= sizeof(int))[-1]; //especially this line,why there is "-1" in here?
  printf("%s\n", t);
}
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: remember `a[i]` == `*(a + i)`

Comment: The `sizeof(int)` is most likely wrong. At least I don't see why it would make sense to increase a pointer to a pointer type by `int` many fields. I suspect it should be `p+=1` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The

```
t = (p+= sizeof(int))[-1];
```

can be rewritten as

```
p += sizeof(int); /* The logic of this doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me */
t = *(p - 1);
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Are you sure? Notice that it's `char **p`.

Comment: @unwind: Oh. Well spotted, thanks. Answer rewritten.